# How can I persist color changes to html elements?

Tags: javascript, html

In my attached code, I display a color picker, then I select a color, then I click the button "contact-info-btn" to change its background color to the selecetd color. However, the change is only good for that window. When refresh the window, it goes back to the old color. is there any way to make this change permanent?

```js
<script>
document.querySelector('#contact-info-btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = document.querySelector("#color-picker").value
        });
```

```html
<label for="color-picker">Color:</label>
    <input type="color" id="color-picker" />
    <form method="post" class="homepg-form" id="homepg-form" >
.
.
<button class="contact-info-btn" id="contact-info-btn" type="button" >İletişim bilgileri</button>
```

Comment: There are a variety of options to persist your data.  A cookie in the browser, local storage in the browser, on your server (which itself would have more options), on a 3rd party service.  If you just want to persist it in the browser then look into using `localStorage` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage:` localStorage is a property that allows JavaScript sites and apps to save key-value pairs in a **web browser with no expiration date.**

```
        function setColorToLocalStorage(value) {
            return localStorage.setItem('bgColor', value);
        }

        function getColorFromLocalStorage() {
            return localStorage.getItem('bgColor');
        }

        function changeBgColor(elem) {
            //get value from local storage if not set in local storage then use default value
            elem.style.backgroundColor = getColorFromLocalStorage() || 'blue';
        }

        const contactBtn = document.querySelector('#contact-info-btn');

        //set/update localstorage bgColor value
        contactBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const bgColorVal = document.querySelector("#color-picker").value;
            // set bgColor to localStorage
            setColorToLocalStorage(bgColorVal);
            //change background color
            changeBgColor(contactBtn);
        });

        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            //on window refresh get bgColor value from localstorage
            changeBgColor(contactBtn);
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="color-picker">Color:</label>
    <input type="color" id="color-picker" />
    <form method="post" class="homepg-form" id="homepg-form">
        <button class="contact-info-btn" id="contact-info-btn" type="button">Change Background</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the value and set it when the page reloads:

```
document.querySelector('#contact-info-btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let color = document.querySelector("#color-picker").value;
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
    localStorage.setItem('contact-info-btn-color', color);
});

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let color = localStorage.getItem('contact-info-btn-color');
    if(color !== null)
        document.querySelector('#contact-info-btn').style.backgroundColor = color;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Joas. This is the answer I was looking for, nice and short. My question can now be closed.